Confusing Dagster error Failure condition: Tried to access asset_partitions_time_window, but the asset is not partitioned
I created a DeltaIOManager in which the load_input method has a filter_datetime_on metadata:
if context.has_partition_key and filter_datetime_on:
            context.log.info(f"Loading partition key: {context.partition_key}")
            start, end = context.asset_partitions_time_window
            start = start - timedelta(days=1)
            end = end + timedelta(days=1)
            context.log.info(f"Filtering time {start}-{end}")

the idea is to filter the data input already to save in-memory data for an asset with a lot of input data. while this works for several input data, it failed for some. the strange thing is all the input data are defined exactly the same:
"df": AssetIn(
            input_manager_key="delta",
            metadata={"filter_datetime_on": "time"},
            key=AssetKey(["silver", "schema", "df"]),
        ),

and most STRANGELY, when it failed, the error is:
dagster._check.CheckError: Failure condition: Tried to access asset_partitions_time_window, but the asset is not partitioned.

however, the error was thrown after the partition_key is loaded, so context.has_partition_key=True. How can the error is thrown if context.has_partition_key=True, and the asset has a partition_definition?
